# Load a different jQuery library from Layout in View for DataTables in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I need to load the specific jQuery library version in a View where I will use the DataTables library.

The problem is that I use jQuery 3.1 for the all project and I include the reference in the _Layout View, but DataTables only allow:

```
Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3
```

How can I, if possible, load a different version of jQuery in that specific view?

EDIT:

Regarding DavidG comment, it seems that the message is based on the Bootstrap jQuery supported library that does not support the jQuery v3.

I am going to update to Bootstrap 3.3.7 to avoid this problem ("Added support for jQuery 3") and use jQuery 3.1.0, but the DataTables problem remains is this case.

EDIT2 (Solution):

I decided to follow Shyju's suggestion to keep everything simple and based in a single stable jQuery version, so I have downgraded jQuery to 2.2.4 (last v2 stable version) and I have keeped Bootstrap to the last version (v3.3.7).

DataTables version remains the same (1.10.12).

Comment: Use a different layout for that view?

Comment: Hi thanks! But this violates the DRY principle :( and I will have to replicate every change of the layout in both Views

Comment: Thinking about this more, how can you even use jQuery 3 if you are running Bootstrap v3? surely your entire project needs v1 or v2?

Comment: Because in the Bootstrap website it says "All plugins require the latest version of jQuery to be included." and it links to version 3.1.0 so I have updated my project to the lastest 3.1.0.version

Comment: What exact version of Bootstrap do you have in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely need to load different version of library for a specific page, you can do something like this.

In the specific action  method which returns the view which has the data table, set a `ViewBag` item

```
public ActionResult List()
{
    ViewBag.NeedsSpecialJQuery = true;
    return View();
}
```

and in the Layout(`_Layout.cshtml`), check for this viewbag item and based on  it's existence/value, conditionally load the jQuery version you need.

```
@{
    if (ViewBag.NeedsSpecialJQuery != null && ViewBag.NeedsSpecialJQuery )
    {
        <script src="path to jQuery 1.9.1 here"></script>
    }
    else
    {
        <script src="path to other jQuery here"></script>
    }
}
```

While this may solve your current problem, I strongly suggest you consider updating your jQuery version (& other libraries depending on jQuery) so that you need only a single version. It might be a little bit of work. But it is worth it. You do not need to look for workarounds like this

Another option is to use a separate Layout file for the specific view

Comment: OP would have to downgrade jQuery to use a single library though.

Comment: My suggestion is to update jQuery and other libraries depending on that to a single stable version or OP will run into isolated problems like this in future

Comment: Actually looking at the question, I can't see how OP can use v3, it's completely incompatible with Bootstrap.

Comment: I never mentioned v3 or v4. My **suggestion** was to adopt to a single stable version to avoid future problems.

Comment: I know, but OP did mention it, which means he has to downgrade to at least v2 and all this goes away.

Comment: @Shyju Thank you for your help. I think that the suggestion of using a single library, in this case v2.2.4, is the better one.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve this using [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

- Load old jQuery library.
- Change its global reference to something other than `$`. e.g. `jQuery2`
- Load new jQuery library

You can continue to use `$` handler for the new library and you can call the name you have given, e.g. `jQuery2`, whenever you want to use the old one

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you only want to install old jQuery library in specific pages, you can combine this answer with [Shyju's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38831406/4180481), you can set a boolean value in their ViewBag and use it like this.

```
@{
    if (ViewBag.NeedsSpecialJQuery != null && ViewBag.NeedsSpecialJQuery)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var jQuery2 = $.noConflict(true);
        </script>
    }

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
}
```

Then you can call `DataTable` like

```
jQuery2("#datatable").DataTable();
```

[**Working jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ozzan/6why85hz/)

Comment: The impact of this is that you are now doubling up jQuery libraries on every page.

Comment: OP will probably want to have jQuery 3 regardless of page, so he will need this. If loading two jQuery libraries on every page is a problem, he can check if the page needs jQuery 2.2.4 before loading that one.

Comment: @DavidG, I implemented [Shyju's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38831406/4180481) to load old jQuery only in specific views.

Comment: I get the error "jQuery1_12_0(...).DataTable is not a function"

Comment: @Patrick, Load DataTables right after you load the old jquery.

Comment: I can't because DataTables is based on the $ jQuery function that does not exist if it's loaded right after, it's searching for the standard jQuery library that is not loaded yet

Comment: If you load the old jquery library, then load DataTable, then call noConflict on jquery, it should be fine. See the updated code.

Comment: @Patrick, See [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ozzan/6why85hz/) for working example

Comment: @Ozan I reaaly thank you for your help but I will follow Shyju's suggestion and keep everything simple based in a single library. Thanks again for your help.